# LinkedIn sdk iOS error if already logged in to LinkedIn App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, linkedin-api

I'm using the iOS LinkedIn SDK to log into my App and retrieve basic profiles.
All works perfectly fine the first time I login, until either I log out, or I close my App.

On attempting to log back into my App with LinkedIn: the usual redirect to the LinkedIn app takes place, but the permissions screen for my app doesn't pop up, it just redirects straight back to my app with the following error:

Error Domain=LISDKAuthError Code=5 "(null)" UserInfo={errorDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. Software caused connection abort, originalDomain=LISDKServerError, errorInfo=PARSING_ERROR}

I can only successfully log back in again if I first close the LinkedIn App, before reopening mine.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on please?

-This doesn't occur on all of my test devices!

-On the device that it does occur on, I also receive the same error in that scenario when running the sample App provided with the LinkedIn SDK.

-The LinkedIn App is up to date.

-The App id, bundle ids etc etc are all set, hence login success half of the time!

-I've tried calling [LISDKSessionManager clearSession] in numerous locations.

Comment: I am getting same issue. Did you solve this issue ?

Comment: Not fixed this no.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be due to which account I use. My device running 10.3.3 handles login just fine, device with 12.0.1 is causing the problems. Unfortunately I don't have any more phones to test with, and am unable to install the LinkedIn App on simulator devices. Please let me know if you find an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Cheeky framework fix alert.

Uncomment out the lines in LISDKSession.h
This allows the correct use of [LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession]

Which is an improvement on what we were working with.
Not yet tested with iOS12...

Comment: which part should I uncomment in LISDKSession.h ? Can you share more details ?

Comment: The 2 lines that are commented out?! - get and set access token, they were commented out in the SDK version I downloaded about a month ago. This means you can now use [LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession] to retrieve the current session rather than asking to create a new session every time. (Which doesn't fix the error, it still occurs if the session has expired and the LinkedIn app is still open, but it is an improvement in that we don't see this error as often as before uncommenting)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. It was mainly reproduced only on iOS 12. The problem is that when you already have a LinkedIn application running, you will not be able to log in through their SDK in your application. On iOS 11, the second time you try to log in after this error, the authorization worked fine. 
I solved this issue by simply showing the user an alert with a message about what he needs to do to authorize.

**Here you can check an example of my implementation in Swift 4:**

```
LISDKSessionManager.createSession(withAuth: ["r_basicprofile"],
                                  state: nil, 
                                  showGoToAppStoreDialog: true,
                                  successBlock: { _ in
                   // Your actions in case of successful authorization
                }, errorBlock: { error in

                    guard let nsError = error as NSError? else {
                        return
                    }

                    if #available(iOS 12.0, *),
                        nsError.code == LISDKErrorCode.SERVER_ERROR.rawValue {
                        // Show alert to user with text - "Please, shut down the LinkedIn app and try login again"
                    } else if nsError.code != LISDKErrorCode.USER_CANCELLED.rawValue {
                        // Handling when user tap on Cancel button in LinkedIn SDK
                    }
})
```

Comment: That doesn't exactly fix the issue does it? Telling your user to go away, close the LinkedIn app, come back to your app and try logging in again.

Comment: This has temporarily solved the problem with the fact that the user becomes clear what to do, so that he can successfully log in.
Unfortunately, the iOS SDK is already considered to be deprecated since 11 December 2017, and LinkedIn suggests switching to OAuth authorization. The other day I hope to finish refactoring with OAuth and update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been battling for a fix for this with LinkedIn for months.
There 'solution' is to kill off the SDK.
Taken from their 'Important updates to the LinkedIn Developers program and APIs' email December 2018:

"Authentication, SDKs, and Plugins: We are also deprecating several obsolete or seldomly-used products and technologies."

"SDKs: Our JavaScript and Mobile Software Development Kits (SDKs) will stop working. Developers will need to migrate to using OAuth 2.0 directly from their apps."

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this two lines of code in **LISDKSession.h**

```
- (LISDKAccessToken *)getAccessToken;

- (void)setAccessToken:(LISDKAccessToken *)accessToken;
```